# Existence of .inputrc breaks paste shortcut

Tags: copy-paste, msysgit

I recently created an .inputrc file in the root directory of my Windows (Vista) user, to override the default history behavior. Today I realized that the 'Insert' key doesn't work for pasting text any more - a tilde character is pasted instead. I found out that this is caused by the .inputrc file being there (an empty file is sufficient). Without the file, insert works just fine.

I tried to restore the insert behavior in the inputrc file, but I don't understand it well enough to make it work. I'm not even sure if I have to override "\e[1~", "\e[2~", or if I have to set some other variable.

Any ideas on how to use both 'Insert' for pasting and .inputrc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the line

```
"\e[2~": paste-from-clipboard
```

to your .inputrc should do it, see [How can I copy and paste into Cygwin console windows?](https://cygwin.com/faq/#faq.using.copy-and-paste) You'll probably also need mappings for the Home, End and Delete keys as show under [Why don't the Home and End keys work in rxvt and vim?](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Configure_RXVT)